How to check type of Ellipsis
I have really specific case, when I need to check types by isinstance in python. And in really rare cases I want to check that value is Ellipsis. For example lets get dict:
customer_ids_map = {
    "1": "aaa",
    "2": ...,
}

But this doesn't work:
isinstance(..., Ellipsis)

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union

And this doesn't work:
isinstance(..., ...)

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union

So is there any elegant way to do this?
P.S. I'm using python3.11

isinstance(..., type(...))?

ohhh really. Thanks!

@jonrsharpe If you have to do type(...), then ... isn't a type but a value, and thus it can be compared directly, not as an is-a relationship. In this case: ... is ... or ... is Ellipsis.

Related: Get python ellipsis (...) type without having to define it as type(...)

You can use type(Ellipsis) or, in Python 3.10+, types.EllipsisType.
>>> isinstance(..., type(Ellipsis))
True
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(..., types.EllipsisType)
True

However, Ellipsis is a singleton (the only instance of EllipsisType), so you can check by identity instead.
>>> ... is Ellipsis
True

